# Is it possible to convert this Outer apply to Left Join?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, apply, outer-join

```
SELECT
    hb.custnum,hb.custname as Cname,dv.custname as [CustName],'0' + hb.cellnum as cellnum,dv.ccelnumber,
    UPPER(hb.subd) as subd,UPPER(dv.BilStAdd) as BilStAdd,hb.entity,dv.BilCtAdd
FROM [cust] as dv
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ##custnumtbl WHERE ##custnumtbl.CustNum = dv.custnum ORDER BY totaldue DESC
) hb
Where 
    '0' + hb.cellnum <> dv.ccelnumber    
    or RTRIM(LTRIM(hb.custname)) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.CustName)) 
    or UPPER(hb.subd) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilStAdd)))
    or UPPER(hb.entity) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilCtAdd)))
```

Comment: If you do not have `CASE Sensitive collation` using `UPPER()` function does not have any affect on the results returned by your query but it can hurt the query performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT
    hb.custnum,hb.custname as Cname,dv.custname as [CustName],'0' + hb.cellnum as cellnum,dv.ccelnumber,
    UPPER(hb.subd) as subd,UPPER(dv.BilStAdd) as BilStAdd,hb.entity,dv.BilCtAdd
FROM [cust] as dv
LEFT JOIN(  
    SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT CustNum, totaldue = MAX(totaldue)
        FROM ##custnumtbl
        GROUP BY CustNum
    )a
    INNER JOIN ##custnumtbl b
        ON b.CustNum = a.CustNum
        AND b.totaldue = a.totaldue
)hb
    ON hb.CustNUm = dv.custnum
Where 
    '0' + hb.cellnum <> dv.ccelnumber    
    or RTRIM(LTRIM(hb.custname)) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.CustName)) 
    or UPPER(hb.subd) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilStAdd)))
    or UPPER(hb.entity) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilCtAdd)))
```

As pointed by M.Ali, if you're not using a case-sensitive collation, you may want to get rid of the `UPPER`.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE:  OP identified the database after this answer was written.  It does not apply to SQL Server 2000.)

Yes, if you want.  The easiest way is to use a window function, such as `row_number()`:

```
SELECT hb.custnum,hb.custname as Cname, dv.custname as [CustName],
       '0' + hb.cellnum as cellnum, dv.ccelnumber,
       UPPER(hb.subd) as subd,UPPER(dv.BilStAdd) as BilStAdd,hb.entity,dv.BilCtAdd
FROM [cust] dv LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustNum ORDER BY totaldue DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ##custnumtbl c
     )  hb
     ON hb.CustNum = dv.custnum AND seqnum = 1
WHERE '0' + hb.cellnum <> dv.ccelnumber  or
      RTRIM(LTRIM(hb.custname)) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.CustName)) or
      UPPER(hb.subd) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilStAdd))) or
      UPPER(hb.entity) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(dv.BilCtAdd)));
```

I think the `outer apply` is likely to have better performance.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to post an answer using `ROW_NUMBER` also. +1

Comment: it works on sql 2008 but when i'm trying to run it on sql 2000 this error occurs: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
and also that's my reason why i'm trying to convert my apply query to left join

Comment: That's because `ROW_NUMBER` is not a valid syntax on SQL Sever 2000.

Comment: @Daviddelacruz . . . I would advise you not to use software that has not been supported for *years*.

Comment: i am adjusting with our client's db and that's why.